# how to get the output of a function called shapiro.test() in a file using R?

Tags: r, mean, median, normal-distribution, uniform-distribution

Assume you have data before and after for a drug. Test whether there is a significant difference due to the drug.

```
>set.seed(10)
>before = rnorm(100)
>set.seed(20)
>after = rnorm(100, mean = 2)
>d = after - before
>shapiro.test(d)
```

this function 'shapiro.test(d)' will print this output:

```
Shapiro-Wilk normality test
data: d
W = 0.98326, p-value = 0.2363
```

now, how to print this output in a file? is there is a function that can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can capture the output and use `cat` to write it to a text file.

```
cat(paste0(capture.output(shapiro.test(d)),collapse = '\n'), file = 'result.txt')
```